# Instructions to update extension in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, installation, composer, git

I'm relatively new to Magento and am currently using version 1.9.3.9.

Out payment system providers (Adyen) have recently provided a new version of their extension with better security (on gitlab this version is designated adyen-magento-2.11.1.)

I'd like to install this new version but I'm concerned that if I do it wrong it will mess up the current version that is installed. I'm assuming that I'd have to log into SSH and use a composer update but I'm unsure about where to load the files and which command to use subsequently.

I cannot seem to find any instructions about how to update this version online.

Comment: do you have ftp ?

Comment: Yes, I use Filezilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unzip the new version of extension
- Check the files if they are added in correct order (app , skin , js)
- cp -rf unzipedextension/* your-magento-root/ (in your terminal)
- clean / flush cache. logout/login in admin .
- Check , if it is upgraded ,